# Material UI TablePagination handle with Redux/React

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui

I am trying to manage the status of a MaterialUI table page.
I am currently using the onChangePage property, but this allows me to only navigate by "adding" pages, i.e. in one direction only, so I cannot return to the previous pages.
My question is as to how to select what kind of event it is depending on which button you click, because if you click either of the two page buttons it only advances to the next page.

This is the table pagination section:

```
<TablePagination
   component="div"
   count= {this.props.logs.length}
   rowsPerPage={this.props.rowsPerPage}
   page={this.props.page}
   backIconButtonProps={{
     'aria-label': 'Previous Page',
   }}
   nextIconButtonProps={{
     'aria-label': 'Next Page',
   }}
   onChangePage={this.handleChangePage}
/>
```

And my handleChangePage looks like this:

```
handleChangePage = (event) => {
  this.props.dispatch(nextPage(this.props.page))
}
```

So, how can I tell the difference between advancing or returning to the previous page with the onChangePage functionality of MaterialUI Tables?

Answer (score 5):

Hi this my solutions :)

```
 <TablePagination
   ...
   backIconButtonProps={{
     'aria-label': 'Previous Page',
     'onClick': this.loadPreviousPage,
   }}
   nextIconButtonProps={{
      'aria-label': 'Next Page',
      'onClick': this.loadNextPage,
  }}
  ...
  />
```

Answer (score 1):

[TablePagination](https://material-ui-next.com/api/table-pagination/) has `page` parameter so keep track of `current page` in redux or in the component by introducing additional parameter `currentPage` which will always point to the  currently rendered page. This way you'll be able to use it to identify the direction a user navigates in paginator by simply comparing `page` and `currentPage` parameters.

```
...
constructor(props, context) {
 super(props, context);

 this.state = {
   data: [
     createData('Cupcake', 305, 3.7),
     createData('Donut', 452, 25.0),
     createData('Eclair', 262, 16.0),
     createData('Frozen yoghurt', 159, 6.0),
     createData('Gingerbread', 356, 16.0),
     createData('Honeycomb', 408, 3.2),
     createData('Ice cream sandwich', 237, 9.0),
     createData('Jelly Bean', 375, 0.0),
     createData('KitKat', 518, 26.0),
     createData('Lollipop', 392, 0.2),
     createData('Marshmallow', 318, 0),
     createData('Nougat', 360, 19.0),
     createData('Oreo', 437, 18.0),
   ],
   page: 0,
   rowsPerPage: 5,
   currentPage: 0,
    };
  }

  handleChangePage = (event, page) => {
   const { currentPage } = this.state;
   //compare page and currentPage params here to solve your problem

   this.setState({ page: page, currentPage: page });
 };
...
```

Comment: Alex, I think you missed the point. Im trying to know how to make a function that depending on the arrow clicked, adds or substract to the page like this:
`handleChangePage = (eventArrowClicked)) => {
if(eventArrowClicked == Next)
  this.props.dispatch(nextPage(this.props.page))
}else{
    this.props.dispatch(previousPage(this.props.page))
}`

Comment: Consider using pagination-action https://material-ui-next.com/demos/tables/#custom-table-pagination-action so it gives you access to button click event.

Comment: Yes but how to apply that to Redux

Comment: instead of triggering event this.props.onChangePage(event, page) in TablePaginationActions dispatch it to the store what, as a result, will trigger reducer and make changes in your table component state. Every component state change will trigger component render method.

Comment: Alex Im not being able to dispatch through the new buttons handlers, It gives me a "this.props.dispatch is not a function" error.

Comment: Make sure your component and redux store are connected (see official redux example https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/todos/src/containers/AddTodo.js) so this way you have access to dispatch method.